# Blogspot Blog HTML help: position and width of post area, sidebar and top widget are wrong

Tags: html, margin, blogger, sidebar

I recently tried to make my popular posts widget and my footer 100%, so they both cover the whole screen.I followed a tutorial on helpblogger.
but after I was done, the sidebar and the main post area had shifted. As another result, the text in the post area is not as wide as the pictures anymore. It all looks a bit messed up. I did manage to make my footer 100% though, it did not work for the widget. And when I tried to move the popular posts widget, a scroll bar appeared at the bottom of my blog, as if the blog was wider than 100%, even though there's nothing when you scrol to the right.
The main problem though is how I can move the main post area and also the sidebar. Is there anyone who can tell me how to fix all this? I have tried a lot and nothing seems so work properly.I am a bit afraid to screw it up even more (but don't worry, of course I have backups).

http://sparkandbark.blogspot.de/

Thank you so much, I would really appreciate any help!
Malin

This image to see where I have highlighted my problems on a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Can you include some code to show what you tried?

Comment: I did this: http://helplogger.blogspot.de/2014/08/blogger-header-footer-full-width.html

(Sorry for not posting it straight away - they didn't let me upload more than 2 links..)